# Rails ActiveRecord getter override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, database-design

So I have a model called Primer which has_many :amplicons. However, in my DB the Amplicons table stores the primer id in either a forward_primer_id or reverse_primer_id column (i.e. not the default primer_id convension). In the Primer model I would like to direct Rails to search the Amplicons table in both of those columns for the primer_id and associate those amplicons with that primer. I think I can write a method in the Primer model to do this but is there a more Rails way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTION 1

```
class Primer
  has_many :forward_amplicons, class_name: "Amplicon", foreign_key: :forward_primer_id
  has_many :reverse_amplicons, class_name: "Amplicon", foreign_key: :reverse_primer_id

  def amplicons
    self.forward_amplicons + self.reverse_amplicons
  end
end
```

OPTION 1 returns an array so you CANNOT chain more conditions, i.e. you CANNOT call `primer.amplicons.where(...)`

OPTION 2

```
class Primer
  def amplicons
    Amplicon.where('forward_primer_id = ? OR reverse_primer_id = ?', self.id, self.id)
  end
end
```

OPTION 2 returns a relation, so you can chain more conditions to it.

Comment: Thanks, I considered option 1 but I did not think to do option 2 like that. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 has_many :forward_amplicons,   class_name: "Amplicon", foreign_key: "forward_primer_id"
 has_many :reverse_amplicons, class_name: "Amplicon", foreign_key: "reverse_primer_id"
```